# How to enter foo-* folder without actually using wildcard or shell expansions?

Tags: shell, command-line, find, cd-command

**Short story**

I'm looking for the command to enter first found `foo-something` directory like:

```
cd foo-*
```

but without using wildcard (or other special shell characters).

**Long story**

As part of the remote drush build script, I'm trying to find the way of entering folder which folder name could change, but it has common prefix. Same example: `drush -y dl ads` or `drush -y dl ads --dev` downloads either `ads-7.x-1.0-alpha1` or `ads-7.x-1.x-dev`).

To make the things more tricky, the command can't consist either [wildcard](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/892) or [escaped semicolon](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/895), because drush is heavily escaping shell aliases.

So `ls *` is escaped into `ls '\''*'\'''` and ending up with `Command ls '*' failed.` error.

I've tried also using `find`, but I can't use `-exec` primary, because [semicolon needs to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913198/why-are-the-backslash-and-semicolon-required-with-the-find-commands-exec-optio), and drush is double escaping it into (`'\''\;'\''`).

Therefore I'm looking to enter `foo-*` folder without using wildcard (or any other special characters, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, etc.) if possible.

I believe the logic of shell escaping is [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/exec.inc#L124) and it is intended to work the same way that `escapeshellarg()` does on Linux. What it does, it's escaping each parameter.

Comment: Does drush allow the use of shell functions? In other words, can you, either on a command line or in a config script, define the shell function  `cdstar() { cd "$1"*; }` and then have access to it under drush?

Comment: @John1024: Probably not ([some examples](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drushrc.php#L77)), but I'll double check.

Comment: @John1024: Drush shell aliases are very similar to [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced). In drush you can only use [shell alias replacements](http://drush.ws/docs/shellaliases.html), but only to use with site alias names (like `'#live' => '@acme.live'`), so you can't put any code there and there are no any other variable replacements features. When I've tried your suggestion, it was escaped into `cdstar() '\''{'\'' cd '\''$1*;'\'' '\''};'\'' cdstar foo`, generating shell syntax error.

Comment: OK.  Too bad.  Just to be clear, `cdstar` is a shell _function_, not an _alias_.   Since the `*` has to come after the argument, making an alias is not sufficient.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do after entering the directory? Are you sure you actually need wildcard `cd`?

Comment: @l0b0: After entering the dir, I'm trying to run either `make` (Makefile) or `phing -f build.xml`. Even if you'll use `phing -f */build.xml` (before entering the dir) - it's still wildcard. Wildcard is needed, because I don't know the dir name (suffixed with the release version) before finding it first.

Comment: Which characters are allowed exactly? Can you pass environment variables with arbitrary content? Can you install an external command that your script would call?

Comment: @Gilles: There is no list of not allowed characters, it's just a method of shell scripting escaping. I believe the logic of it it's [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/exec.inc#L352). It's intended to work the same way that escapeshellarg() does on Linux.

Comment: You can reliably shell escape a shell command with `alias`. For example: `shell_quote() { set -- "$(alias "cmd=$1"; alias cmd)"; printf %s\\n "${1#*=}"; }; escaped=$(shell_quote 'ls *'); printf 'double_escaped=%s\n' "$(shell_quote "$escaped")"`

Comment: Anything you try to do will require some shell metacharacters. If you don't use wildcards, you'll need to pipe something. My best idea is to put what you want to do in a script, and call that script from `drush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does drush mung backticks and vertical bars? 
If not, you could use

```
cd `ls | grep foo- | head -n 1`
```

If backticks don't work, but `|`, `$`, `(` and `)` do, then you could change the above to

```
cd $(ls | grep foo- | head -n 1)
```

If `|` doen't work, but `$`, `(` and `)` do, then you could do

```
cd $(myprog)
```

where `myprog` is a script that you write to determine the directory name.

Also -- I don't understand how you might be able to use `find` to help you do a `cd`,
but, can you end your `-exec` with a `+`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your solutions, `head` idea sounds promising. Re: `find`, I've tried something like: `find . -name build.xml -print -exec echo phing -f {} \; -quit` (where build.xml is one of the files within the folder) or something like `find . -name build.xml -exec cd {} \; -quit` (it's not complete, because path needs to be converted into dir), but it won't work anyway, because after run semicolon was escaped twice breaking the syntax.

Comment: Well, the point I was making in my last sentence was that `find ... -exec cd {} \;` isn't going to work, since `cd` is a shell builtin command and not an executable program. You might be able to do something like `find ... -exec sh -c "cd $1; (other commands)" -- {} +`, but that's starting to get messy.

Comment: Why not just `cd "$( IFS="\n" find . type d -name some*glob | head -n1 -dpeth 1)"`?

Comment: Also, it's generally considered a Very Bad Idea to parse the output of `ls`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for extended discussion of why this can do terrible things to kittens.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: (1) Does `IFS="\n"` really do any good in your suggested command? (2) Haven’t you heard that deferred wildcards/globs (i.e., arguments to `-name` and `-iname` in `find`) should always be quoted? (3) Did you miss the part of the question where the OP said that he ***couldn’t use*** `*`? (4) `find … | head -n1` chops up names with newlines in them just as badly as `ls | head -n 1`. … (cont’d)

Comment: (cont’d) … (5) My version of `head` does not have a `-d`, `-p`, `-e`, `-t`, or `-h` option. Perhaps you meant to say `-depth` instead of `-dpeth`? And perhaps you meant to include it in the `find` command rather than tacking it on to the `head` command? (6) I’ve heard the tale about parsing the output of `ls`, but extraordinary times call for extraordinary measures. The OP seems to believe that he has a general idea of what his directory names are going to look like, and, after four hours, nobody else has posted an answer that tries to comply with the constraints of the question.

Comment: [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), unanchored `grep`, [backticks](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), oh my.

Comment: @G-Man (1) Setting `IFS` is how you handle newlines in filenames, as you ask in (4).  (2) Yes, good point, that should have been a quoted `"some*glob"`.  (3) And here is where my suggestion fails utterly, though at that point I was more commenting on the answer than on the question itself.  Still, yes, my suggestion was not helpful to the original context of not being able to use `*`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: `IFS` is interpreted by the shell, and _only_ the shell, as far as I know. Do you believe that setting `IFS` will modify the way `head` works? I don't think so. If I have directories named `abc(newline)def` and `ghi(newline)jkl`, then `find . -type d` is going to output `./abc(newline)def(newline)./ghi(newline)jkl(newline)`, and `head -n 1` on that will produce `./abc`.

Comment: I was using `IFS` to change the output of `find`, but yes, on further reflection, the newlines would still be there to mess with the piped input to `head`.  I sit corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [final requirement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162779/how-to-enter-foo-folder-without-actually-using-wildcard-or-shell-expansions?noredirect=1#comment266743_162779) you don't need `cd`; you can do the following:

```
find . -type d -name 'foo-*' -exec make -C {} ';'
```

and

```
find . -type d -name 'foo-*' -exec phing -f {}/build.xml ';'
```

The asterisks are handled by `find` internally, and I believe this is POSIX compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatelly the problem is with escaped semicolon as already mentioned, it gets double escaped into `'\''\;'\''` and breaking the whole syntax. If I won't escape the semicolon, `find` command would complain.

Comment: Tested 1st example: `"!find . -type d -name 'foo-*' -exec make -C {} \;"`, it's get escaped as `find . -type d -name '\'''\''\'\'''\''foo-*'\''\'\'''\'''\'' -exec make -C '\''{}'\'' '\''\;'\'''` and parsed on the remote shell as: `find . -type d -name ''\''foo-*'\''' -exec make -C '{}' '\;'`.

Comment: Similar to the 2nd: `find . -type d -name 'foo-*' -exec phing -f {}/build.xml \;`, parsed on the remote shell as: `find . -type d -name ''\''foo-*'\''' -exec phing -f '{}/build.xml' '\;'`. I don't think drush is following any POSIX compability, it's just escaping everything when you're trying to be smarter.

Comment: You can *quote* the semicolon instead of escaping it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try using `locate` utility, e.g.:

```
updatedb -o ~/tmp.db -l0 -U $PWD; cd $(locate -d ~/tmp.db -l 1 -b -r foo-)
```

For more complex regex pattern check `info locate`.